# table with first column fits content and second column overflow-x auto

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a 2 columns table with the following properties :

1. the table must fit to its parent container
2. the first column must fit to its content
3. the second column content must be horizontally scrollable if it
   exceed the table width.

► I began with the following code :

*(css here is just to "see" the main container and the table - width: 500px is just for the example, it could be any value)*

```css
.main {
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="one">content_1</td>
      <td class="two">
        <div class="content">short string</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td class="one">content_2</td>
      <td class="two">aVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryLongStringWithoutSpaces</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  
</div>
```

Point **1** is **not ok** : The table does not fit to its container

Point **2** is **ok** : first column fit to its content

point **3** **not ok** : as the table does not fit its container, I can't apply an `overflow: auto` for now

► the only way I found to make the table fit its container is to add the following css properties : `table-layout: fixed` & `width: 100%`

then I can add `width:100%`, `display: inline-block` & `overflow: auto` to the second column to make the content scrollable if it exceed the table width

```css
.main {
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.two {
  width:100%;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="one">content_1</td>
      <td class="two">
        <div class="content">short string</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td class="one">content_2</td>
      <td class="two">aVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryLongStringWithoutSpaces</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  
</div>
```

Point **1** is now **ok** : The table fit to its container

Point **2** is **not ok** anymore : `table-layout: fixed` makes the two columns

point **3** now **ok** : the content of the second column is scrollable if its too long

► So now I'm looking for a solution to have the 3 points OK.

to get the closest to wha I need, I set `width: 50px` to the `.one` class, but in my project I can't do that as I have several tables with differents content size in the first column, so I need the first column's size to be set automatically to fit to the content as in the first snippet.

Any help ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `word-break:break-all` for `.two`

```css
.main {
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;

}

table {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  width: 100%;
}
.two{
  word-break:break-all;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="one">content_1</td>
      <td class="two">
        <div class="content">short string</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td class="one">content_2</td>
      <td class="two">aVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryLongStringWithoutSpaces</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  
</div>
```

Comment: It's a good option, Thank you ! I'll probably use this one if I can't find a way to make it with overflow :)